# Why does my external CSS not work in FF or IE, but does in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When I run my (very basic) page in Chrome, it shows the title and list in the correct size, colour and position. Also the background image fits to the screen. But when I run my page in FF or IE, there is no background image and the title and list haven't got my CSS position, colour or size.

I have copied my code below. My question is: how can I make my title and list show up on my web page in all/most browsers in the correct size, colour and position to what I have set it to in my CSS? Also for the background image to be shown as well. I hope this isn't too general. Please help!

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="C:///****/*****/Desktop/FifaStream1.0/indexstyle.css"/>
    <title> Fifa Stream </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="Title1"> <font color="grey"> Fifa  </font color> <font color="red">Stream </font color></h1>
    <nav class="IndexList">
      <li> <a href="HomePage.html"> Home <br> <br> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="YoutubePage.html"> Youtube <br> <br> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="AboutUs.html"> About Us <br> <br> </a> </li>
    <nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
  background:url(fifa13messi.png);
  -moz-background:url(fifa13messi.png);
  background-size:100%;
  -moz-background-size:100%; /* Old Firefox */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#Title1 {
  position:relative;
  left:5%;
  top:5%;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.IndexList {
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
  left:5%;
  top:40%;
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

It would a great help if anyone could explain where or why I'm going wrong.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using the absolutely ancient <font> tag, not only that it wouldn't even be valid for ancient versions of HTML. It will never render correctly if your markup isn't valid.

Comment: Ah okay, I only used it because I wasn't sure how to change the title words to two seperate colours.(Fifa="white" & Stream="Red") etc.

Comment: If you wanted to split an <h1> tag into 2 different colors, you could put each part of it into its own <span> tag, and then style accordingly using CSS. HTML is not meant for presentation, it's meant for the semantic structure of the page. You want to strive for all presentation to be in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `<li>` elements can't be children of the `<nav>` element - they can only be children of the `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements...

Comment: I wish our lecturer would explain simple stuff like this to us. But thanks. Any ideas why the background image doesnt work? haha.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working in IE and Chrome, just not Firefox. Finally some progress :)

Comment: Haha okay :) Unfortunately it didnt work, but thanks for all your help. 4am, time to sleep i think. Hopefully will sort it tomorrow!

Comment: Technically the the `background:url(....);` line of CSS is wrong, or at least incomplete.  It should be something like `background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image;` or you could just use `background-image:url(...);`

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  You code should be fine as all of the different values in the background tag are optional.  You could try putting quotes around the file name, e.g. `background-image:url('fifa13messi.png');`

Answer (score 1):

The `type` attribute should be `text/css`, not `txt/css`. IE and Firefox are (correctly) rejecting it for the mismatch.

Comment: I changed it to text/css but unfortunately it didnt make a difference (n)

Answer (score 1):

First thing I want to say is try to do smart work, use some html eiditor, like dreamweaver or  some other that provide hints forcodig.

Now point by point here are list of problems in you coding

1. Type attribute for link css should be text/css.    Not. Txt/css
2. Try to close tags just after creating it.   This will always make shure all tags are closed.   Bcz your nav tagi not closed,but  created two nav tags without closing them.
3. Li tag should be wrapped with 'o' or 'ul'

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately we arent allow to use dreamweaver, but i do use sublime text 2 which colours the text, so helps alittle when checking for errors. 

Iv gone through your points and Firefox still wont recognise my CSS (n)

Answer (score -1):

Your `<nav>` tag needs a `</nav>` closing tag, not a second `<nav>`.

Comment: Sorry silly mistake. That still hasn't sorted it. I'v been stuck on this for ages, thanks though.